# How to simulate a mouse click on a started process

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am trying to open an application through C# using `Process.Start()` and then simulate a mouse click on the application.

When I run the application, the mouse click occurs in the left top corner, which is not what I want.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
                             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy,
                                          int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            AddTextToListBox1(label1);            
        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
           // AddTextToListBox2(label2);
        }).Start();
    }

    private void AddTextToListBox1(Label label)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            stringDelegate sd = new stringDelegate(AddTextToListBox1);
            this.Invoke(sd, new object[] { label1 });
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = this.ToString()+"Hi";
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C://xyz//xyz.exe";
            p.Start();
            IntPtr hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
        }
    }

    private void AddTextToListBox2(Label label)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            stringDelegate sd = new stringDelegate(AddTextToListBox2);
            this.Invoke(sd, new object[] { label1 });
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = "done";
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
            int X = 579;
            int Y = 637;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, X, Y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);              
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're wanting to do anything more complex than a single mouse click, you might want to consider using the UI Automation system, rather than trying to craft raw events.

Comment: right now I just want simple mouse click.

Comment: Why can't you use UIAutomation?

Answer (score 0):

I think mouse_event will only raise event in current app because it doesn't take `hwnd` on params. My experience in this area is really low, but I've done some research. Look at SendMessage function.

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Sends the specified message to a window or windows. 
>   The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window 
>   and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

You can send many messages with it, including mouse events